# What would happen if we remove the battery from a DC motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction, batteries

The construction of a DC motor and an AC generator is nearly the same, the only difference is that a dc motor has battery while the ac generator doesn't have the battery. If we remove the battery, won't it turn into a DC generator? Because, according to Faraday's law, if electric current can generate a magnetic field, then a magnetic field can also induce EMF, on the basis of which the AC generator works.

Comment: What do you mean, a motor and a generator are "nearly the same"? They work on completely different principles.

Comment: @Yejus You should hook a voltmeter to a small permanent magnet field DC motor (common in motorized toys) and spin the motor. I also have an older Onan  110 and 220vac generator that was made to be started by 12vdc applied to the generator. In fact I test the older Harley Davidson generators by grounding (negative) the housing  and applying 12vdc positive to the armature connection to make the generator spin. Asad is correct.

Comment: @Yejus I do agree that they work on completely different basis but regarding that I have mentioned above that if we remove the battery from a DC motor, won't it just become a DC generator? I need help regarding that.

Comment: @Yejus  "I do agree that they work on completely different basis" See part (b) of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

(a) In an important sense, you don't even have to remove the battery to turn a motor into a generator. When you run a motor off a power supply, as the motor turns, and the flux linking the coils changes, it generates an emf. This is often called a back-emf because it's in the opposite sense to the power supply's emf. It is the work done per second by the current against this back-emf that provides the mechanical power output of the motor.

If the resistance of the motor's coils is $r$, then, using Kirchhoff's loop law:
$$\mathscr E_{\text {supply}}-\mathscr E_{\text {back}}=Ir\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{that is}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathscr E_{\text {supply}}=\mathscr E_{\text {back}}+Ir$$
Multiplying through by the current, $I$,
$$\mathscr E_{\text {supply}}I=\mathscr E_{\text {back}}I+I^2r$$
that is: Electrical power in = Mechanical power out + Power dissipated in motor's coils.

With nothing connected across the coil(s), that is on open circuit, the machine simply acts as a generator when we turn the spindle. But if we connect a load resistor across the coil(s) we get a current through them, and the machine now acts as a motor as well as a generator. The torque produced by the motor opposes our turning of the spindle, so we have to apply a torque as we turn. This is how we 'pay' for the electrical power that is now being supplied to the load!

(b)  Not only does a coil that can turn in a magnetic field act both as motor and generator, but the basic physics of these two functions is the same, namely the magnetic Lorentz force acting on the charge carriers in the wire of the coil(s). The component of this force at right angles to the wire provides the motor effect, and the component parallel to the wire gives rise to the generated emf.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't matter if we remove the battery or not, induced emf will still be produced, correct? The windings move with or without the presence of a battery. but if it is true, then why do we purposefully use a battery for motor? isn't it a generator and a battery simultaneously without the usage of battery? If we amplify the loops, the magnetic field strength, the current, and the area won't it have a  rotating force which is generally used in appliances?

Comment: (i) "so it doesn't matter if we remove the battery or not, induced emf will still be produced, correct?" Yes, that's right. (ii) "why do we purposefully use a battery for motor?" Because the motor won't turn otherwise! Note that the back emf generated as the motor turns is smaller than the battery emf and in the opposite direction. It doesn't help the coil turn, quite the reverse! I'm sure you know Lenz's law.